# Deployment failed: Component Errors: Duplicate picklist value:Yes_or_No - No

Tags: deployment, picklist, error, change-set

> **Issue:** When validating a change set of 300 items into production, I
>   received one component error:
>
> **API Name:** Opportunity.New_Integrated_Payments_Customer | 
>   **Type:** Record Type | **Line:** 5028 | **Column:** 21 | **Error Message:** Duplicate picklist value:Yes_or_No - No

---

**Screenshot:**
[image: Deploy Error]

---

I opened Eclipse and downloaded the Opportunity object from my Dev org (sending org), and also from my receiving org (Production), and looked at the metadata through the text editor. Each metadata has a different picklist or value on line 5028 (obviously, because dev is different), but neither of the two has anything on line 5028 in the Opportunity object that is even in my ChangeSet.

> **Question:** At this point, I don't know where to go. How do I further debug this/determine the picklist that is actually the root
>   cause **without** removing everything from the ChangeSet and trying
>   over and over until I isolate the issue? Is the line 5028 referring to
>   a line in the ChangeSet, rather than a line in Dev or Prod? If so, how
>   can I read the metadata file from the ChangeSet to determine what is
>   listed on that line?

Comment: It would be the line number in the metadata definition, I would think. If you included that `RecordType` in the deployment, click the `View Source` link next to it.

Comment: Hey @AdrianLarson, thanks for commenting. Totally 100% right, I viewed source and line 5028 is a duplicate value in a picklist called Yes_or_No. However, upon looking at all of the other picklist values in the record type, I notice that the custom picklists still end in __c in the source (`<picklist>Wireless__c</picklist>`) - The Yes_or_No picklist however doesn't end in __c, and has the "No" value repeated 5 or 6 times. Do you know what this Yes_or_No picklist on Opportunities is?

Comment: I sure don't. Good luck with that! At least now you have a slightly better clue...

Comment: Great, @AdrianLarson doesn't know something... I'm doomed. Thanks anyway sir

Comment: Is it a Global Picklist?

Comment: @DaveHumm Yes! In fact it appears that it is! And its named Yes_or_No. Found the culprit. Strange that they've chosen not to append __c to the end of Global Picklist Value sets. So now I've found the culprit, but not sure on the fix. The Yes and No values are only listed in the global picklist once. They are the only 2 values in the global picklist, but the global is assigned to 8 different picklists on the opportunity object. Is there a fix for this, or is this more likely a deployment bug of some sort? I'm thinking maybe manually create the global picklist in prod, not ideal but will test.

Comment: @MorganMarchese - have you tried adding the Global Value Set for the Global picklist to the change set?

Comment: @DaveHumm I checked the change set and the Global Value Set is in the change set already and when I view source on it there are only 2 values. Its only when I view source on the record type that it shows the values duplicated multiple times. I assume this is because the value set is assigned to 8 picklists, so its repeating the values 8 times? Starting to feel more and more like a deployment bug

Comment: @MorganMarchese Does sound like it. I'll try and duplicate when I have some time.

Comment: Removing the Yes_or_No global picklist from the change set and manually creating it in production first didn't solve the problem, and I can't find a way to change the global value picklists back to standard picklists. My entire deployment is blocked now unless I manually delete and re-create all 8 picklists and their associated dependencies.